# MySQL popular searches query, how to add to count instead of insert new if the search already exists?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

URL for reference: [**jobs.sitesixteen**](http://jobs.sitesixteen.com/search/results/web+design-jobs-within-100-miles-of-New%20York-NY-you-can-telecommute-to%2a)

I currently have a query that runs every time a job search is performed that adds that job search to the searches_performed table. This inserts fine:

```
INSERT INTO `searches_performed`
            (`state`,
             `city`,
             `distance`,
             `term`,
             `description`,
             `telecommute`)
VALUES      ( 'NY',
              'New York',
              '100',
              'web design',
              '1',
              '1' )
```

There is also a 'count' column in this table with a default value of 1.

My aim is to — without the aid of Php and multiple queries — check to see if a search I intend to insert exists and if it does not, add it. If the search I intend to insert does exist, I would simply like to add 1 to that row's 'count' column.

As always, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use : INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

i.e: Define a primary key on the search fields and then use

```
INSERT INTO `searches_performed`
            (`state`,
             `city`,
             `distance`,
             `term`,
             `description`,
             `telecommute`)
VALUES      ( 'NY',
              'New York',
              '100',
              'web design',
              '1',
              '1' ) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counts=counts+1;
```

Comment: I ended up removing distance, description and telecommute from the insert and added a unique key that is the md5 of the city, state and title. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This only triggers if a unique index is duplicated

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to accomplish this using [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). You'll have to make the the search terms are a key. See the page above for examples.